# How to find character entities in string use nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string after

```html
<!--
document.write("<a rel='nofollow' href='mailto:&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;'>&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;</a>");
//-->
```

how to get htmlentities in tag

```
&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;
```

Comment: Does it always look at that? starting with doc write, and a tag and then `href`

Answer (score 2):

#### If you want to get each html entity:

```js
const rgx = /\&\#\d+;/g;
const string = "<a rel='nofollow' href='mailto:&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;'>&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;</a>";
    
while ((match = rgx.exec(string)) !== null) console.log(match[0]);
```

#### If you want to get all of them together:

```js
const rgx = /(\&\#\d+;)+/;
const string = "<a rel='nofollow' href='mailto:&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;'>&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;</a>";
    
console.log(rgx.exec(string)[0]);
```

This RegEx has the advantage to work on every string that contains HTMLEntities, regardless of the surroundings.

Comment: Hope it solves your problem!

If this answer helps you, consider accepting it as the correct one by clicking on the little checkmark below the score of the answer, or one of the other answers where you thanked the respective authors :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const html = "<a rel='nofollow' href='mailto:&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;'>&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;</a>";

const match = /<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/.exec(html);
console.log('match: ', match[1]);
console.log('is-correct: ', match[1] === '&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;');
```

---

This works, but I don't understand why you would have that many entity encodings in your markup.

Comment: thanks @FK82, it working. I parsing the website and email is encrypted

Answer (score 1):

This works, just using `split("")`. I think this is a better solution because this does not care what is inside of `href`, so it could be any string, and it will split it out.

```js
const a = `document.write("<a rel='nofollow' href='mailto:&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;'>&#116;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#113;&#117;&#97;&#110;&#103;&#100;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#50;&#55;&#48;&#52;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;</a>");`

const array = a.split("mailto:")[1].split("</a>\");")[0]

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Thanks you @leogoesger

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
const matches = str.match(/&#\d+;/);
```

Comment: It would be a better answer if you explained the regex you answered